# Targeting every nth index from x to y in Twig

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, twig, twig-filter

I'm having a problem with the `loop.index` in a `for` loop for a complex grid (marked up as a simple single level HTML list). I have a `loop_index` variable in a twig partial for a grid "cell" (a `<li>`) which is equal to `loop.index`.

Initially I had this simple specific numbers based check for the first items in the loop.

```
{% set class = 'green' %}
{% if (loop_index > 1 and loop_index < 5) or (loop_index > 7 and loop_index < 12) %}
   {% set class = 'orange' %}
{% endif %}
```

But now it should be extended to include possibly unlimited number of items in the loop. Therefore not only items 2-4 and 8-11 would become `orange`, but also 15-18 etc.

Basically I need to cycle through 2 classes (orange, green) in this way:

- 2-4 - orange
- (repeating pattern begins from here:)
- 5-7 - green (batch of 3)
- 8-11 - orange (batch of 4)
- 12-14 - green (batch of 3)
- 15-18 - orange (batch of 4)
- 19-21 - green (batch of 3)
- 22-25 - orange (batch of 4)
- ...

I tried to employ [`batch`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html) and [`cycle`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html) for that, but they seem to be inappropriate for this. `batch` doesn't seem to work with "unlimited" loops and `cycle` seems not ok for a repeated pattern with batches of same items (as opposed to looping through ungrouped single items). `divisible by` also didn't work for me as needed in this case.

How can I change the classes depending on the value of `loop.index`? I can't work with the `for` loop or outside of it here — all the work needs to be done inside the grid "cell" partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [rest of the division](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#math). Here a working solutions:

```
{% for i in 1..30 %}
 {% set class = 'green' %}
 {% set loop_index = loop.index %}
 {% if (loop_index %7 >= 1 and loop_index %7 < 5) %}
   {% set class = 'orange' %}
 {% endif %}
    * {{ i }} {{class}}
{% endfor %}
```

This will output as:

```
* 5 green
* 6 green
* 7 green
    * 8 orange
    * 9 orange
    * 10 orange
    * 11 orange
* 12 green
* 13 green
* 14 green
    * 15 orange
    * 16 orange
    * 17 orange
    * 18 orange
* 19 green
* 20 green
* 21 green
    * 22 orange
    * 23 orange
    * 24 orange
    * 25 orange
* 26 green
* 27 green
```

You can check the output [in this working twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ivota1)

Comment: Thank you Matteo, it's working well! I wasn't aware that such an expression `loop_index %7 >= 1` is possible.